# How do I process the OAuth2 redirection URI in my Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, oauth-2.0

First of all - this is my first attempt at creating a chrome extension; and I don't understand the way authorization works, AT ALL.

I'm assuming the fix is easy; but I just can't wrap my head around this.

What I've done so far:

- I've created an extension, and loaded it into my chrome
- I've created a project in my google cloud console
- I've added an OAuth 2.0 Client ID, in which I added the redirect URI as following:
  `https://MY_EXTENSION_ID.chromiumapp.org/oauth2`
- Then in my manifest.json, I've added the client ID that I've obtained from the google cloud console as following

```js
"oauth2": {
        "client_id": "MY_CLIENT_ID.apps.googleusercontent.com",
        "scopes": [
            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets"
        ]
    },
```

- In my popup.html I've added a button that will redirect me to the OAuth authorization screen - which goes well.
- My popup.js looks like this:

```js
// OAuth-configuration
const GOOGLE_API_KEY = 'MY_API_KEY';
const CLIENT_ID = 'CLIENT_ID.apps.googleusercontent.com';
const scopes = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets';
const redirectUri = chrome.identity.getRedirectURL('oauth2');

// login button click event

loginButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
const authUrl = `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=${CLIENT_ID}&redirect_uri=${encodeURIComponent(redirectUri)}&scope=${encodeURIComponent(scopes)}&response_type=token`;

// Open new tab to redirect to google login panel
chrome.tabs.create({ url: authUrl, active: true });

});
```

- After this, I get redirected to the screen and am able to log in. After logging however, and being redirected to the URL containing my token, this is what the page looks like:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fH1rSNUuCcwc63UpJB8cpL0oHHWoduk8/view?usp=sharing

What should I do to solve this? Is there any extra info I should provide?

chrome.identity doesn't really solve for the problem I'm experiencing, since it doesn't work with Opera

btw: I don't know if my extension & client id is senstive information that I should keep for my self, please let me know.